# SQL Server tables: what is the difference between @, # and ##?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, what is the difference between a @ table, a # table and a ## table?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

`#table` refers to a local (visible to only the user who created it) temporary table.

`##table` refers to a global (visible to all users) temporary table.

`@variableName` refers to a variable which can hold values depending on its type.

Comment: Your definition of #table is not totally correct. It is not limited to the user but rather the connection. If a user has multiple connections it will only be visible to the connection that created the #table in the first place.

Comment: @DavinStuder has offered a crucial clarification.  The distinction between a table visible to the user vs. a table visible only on the current connection is very important.

Comment: @DavinStuder how view multiple connections for  user ? the same connection string ?

Answer (score 27):

Have a look at

- [Temporary Tables vs. Table Variables
  and Their Effect on SQL Server
  Performance](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/temp-tables-vs-variables/)
- [Differences between SQL Server
  temporary tables and table
  variables](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1556)
- [Temp Tables and Table Variables:
  When To Use What And Why](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/programming-life/temp-tables-and-table-variables-when-to-use-what-and-why-part-1-16116)

Comment: I realize this is from a long while back, but since this is a link-only answer (and the first link is dead), could it be updated with the main takeaways from each of the links?

Answer (score 7):

`#` and `##` tables are actual tables represented in the temp database.  These tables can have indexes and statistics, and can be accessed across sprocs in a session (in the case of a global temp table, it is available across sessions).

The @table is a table variable.

For more: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables

Comment: And the table variable will also live in the tempDB database, if its size is too big to hold in memory.

Answer (score 7):

```
CREATE TABLE #t
```

Creates a table that is only visible on and during that CONNECTION
the same user who creates another connection will not be able to see table #t from the other connection.

```
CREATE TABLE ##t
```

Creates a temporary table visible to other connections. But the table is dropped when the creating connection is ended.

Comment: `SqlConnection.Open()` with the *same connection string* is The ***same CONNECTION***  ?

Comment: no, it's a connection to the same database, but almost certainly not the same connection.

Answer (score 5):

I would focus on the differences between #table and @table.  ##table is a global temporary table and for the record in over 10 years of using SQL Server I have yet to come across a valid use case.  I'm sure that some exist but the nature of the object makes it highly unusable IMHO.

The response to @whiner by @marc_s is absolutely true: it is a prevalent myth that table variables always live in memory.  It is actually quite common for a table variable to go to disk and operate just like a temp table.

Anyway I suggest reading up on the set of differences by following the links pointed out by @Astander.  Most of the difference involve limitations on what you can't do with @table variables.

Comment: I have 5 separate stored procedure that perform different parts of a calculation and output a single result. For auditing I want to see intermediate values and so does the auditor. I adjusted my procedures to dump some out to a ## Temp table so we can both view them but they aren't retained (they are only needed during audits).

There is a valid use case for you (IMHO!).

Comment: @Ryan why is ##Table valid when you could have used dbo.Table? I don't consider it a valid use case when all you've done is saved yourself from typing a DROP statement.

Comment: I don't want to give the auditor DROP permissions on my DB. I also don't want to have to come back and tidy up after he is done. With a temp table he can run the query as often as he likes and I know when he is done he isn't leaving a footprint in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

if you need a unique global temp table, create your own with a Uniqueidentifier Prefix/Suffix and drop post execution if an if object_id(....  The only drawback is using Dynamic sql and need to drop explicitly.