# Group by date and count of entries

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, statistics

I'll make it short, the table looks like this:

```
| id (int) | registerDate (DATETIME)
|----------|-----------------
| 1        | 2014-07-29 12:00:00
| 2        | 2014-08-01 12:00:00
| 3        | 2014-08-01 12:00:00
| 4        | 2014-08-01 12:00:00
| 5        | 2014-08-02 12:00:00
| 6        | 2014-08-02 12:00:00
| 7        | 2014-08-04 12:00:00
```

If today is 2014-08-05, I want results like this:

```
| registerDate (DATETIME) | count (int)
| 2014-08-04              | 1
| 2014-08-03              | 0
| 2014-08-02              | 2
| 2014-08-01              | 1
| 2014-07-31              | 0
| 2014-07-30              | 0
| 2014-07-29              | 1
```

So I want the count of registered users in the past week (daily).
I tried to find it out on google (unsuccessfully) - however, I hope you can help.

Comment: Can you make it clear? 2014-08-01 12:00:00 appears thrice, but in ur result it shows 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT registerDate, count(registerDate) FROM [TABLE] WHERE
registerDate between (GETDATE()-7) and GETDATE()   
group by registerDate  
order by registerDate desc
```

This will take a table like:

```
2   |1905-06-26 00:00:00.000
4   |2014-08-03 00:00:00.000
5   |2014-08-02 00:00:00.000
1   |2014-08-01 00:00:00.000
3   |2014-07-01 00:00:00.000
6   |2010-07-01 00:00:00.000
7   |2015-07-01 00:00:00.000
8   |2014-08-28 00:00:00.000
9   |2014-08-26 00:00:00.000
10  |2014-08-26 00:00:00.000
```

And create:

```
2014-08-28 00:00:00.000 |   1
2014-08-26 00:00:00.000 |   2
```

The problem with this is it doesn't show the days that are not in the table.
Give me a little more time, I'll have an updated version.

EDIT:

Now the more complex one...

```
-- Declare how far back you want to go
DECLARE @DAYSBACK int = 6

-- Select into a temptable
select CONVERT(date, registerDate) as RegDate, count(registerDate) as DateCount 
  INTO #temptable 
  from Temp where registerDate between (GETDATE()-6) and GETDATE()
  group by registerDate order by registerDate desc

-- Check to see if exists if not, insert row
WHILE @DAYSBACK >= 0 BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (select top 1 1 from #temptable 
                   where RegDate= CONVERT(date, (GETDATE()-@DAYSBACK))
                   group by RegDate)
        INSERT INTO #temptable values ((GETDATE()-@DAYSBACK), 0)
    SET @DAYSBACK = @DAYSBACK -1
END

-- Select what you want
select * from #temptable order by RegDate desc

-- Drop the table you created.
DROP TABLE #temptable
```

Using the same table as above, it will output:

```
Register Date | Date Count
--------------------------
2014-08-28    | 1
2014-08-27    | 0
2014-08-26    | 2
2014-08-25    | 0
2014-08-24    | 0
2014-08-23    | 0
2014-08-22    | 0
```

Comment: Is #temptable a real table in a database (does this create a table)? However, the result clearly matches my expectations. Thanks for this. Do I have to create a procedure for this (it's about MySQL and I'm using phpmyadmin).

Comment: @BlackHat The `#temptable` creates a local temporary table that is only visible in the current session. 

I would probably throw it into a stored procedure, it will create a plan for it and be faster every time it is run.

Some short reading that explains it rather nicely. [Here](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/05/04/temporary-tables-ms-sql-server/) 

A similar question regarding #, ##, and @ : [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219714/sql-server-tables-what-is-the-difference-between-and)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select registerDate  = convert(date,t.registerDate) ,
       registrations = count(*)
from dbo.my_special_registration_table t
where t.registrationDate >= dateadd(day,-7,convert(date,getdate()))
group by convert(date,t.registerDate)
order by 1
```

If you try to filter out registrations older than 7 days using something like `datediff()`:

```
where datediff(day,t.registrationDate,getdate()) <= 7
```

you turned the column `registrationDate` into an *expression*. As a result the query optimizer can't make use of any indices that might apply, thus forcing a table scan. If you table is large, performance is likely to be ... suboptimal.