# TSQL, Why use a global table (##table) within a stored procedure when it is recreated every time the stored procedure is run?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on optimizing some older tsql queries.

I have found several that use ##table which is a global temporary table.

[SQL Server tables: what is the difference between @, # and ##?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219714/sql-server-tables-what-is-the-difference-between-and)

What I am seeing though is that at the top of these stored procedures it checks if this ##table exists and if so it drops the table then proceeds to recreate this ##table.  These are the only stored procedures using this ##table.

My question is there any reason why you would use a global table (##table) when you just recreate it everytime?  Is there some efficiency gained via the ##table over the #table (local table)?

I want to replace these ##tables with #tables due to the fact that they aren't truly global but don't want to cause an efficiency issue or cause an issue due to my lack of knowledge surrounding these ##table(s).  (It is also causing some split second issues when the queries are ran at the same time where both are trying to delete and recreate the table, when in reality if they were internal tables #table, this issue would never occur)

First time I have ever ran into ##tables.

Comment: Is it created using dynamic SQL or just static SQL?

Comment: No, it is not dynamic, just your standard tsql stored procedure.

Comment: Based on your description seems  you should just convert them to local ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tDifference betwen @, #, and ## are:

`@` is visible only in in batch where it is declared. Example

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE (c INT NOT NULL ); 

INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1) --correct
GO
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(2) --error. after GO it is another batch
```

`#` is visible in session that created that temp local table. Example

```
CREATE TABLE #t (c INT NOT NULL ); 

INSERT INTO #t  VALUES(1) --correct
GO
INSERT INTO #t  VALUES(2) --correct
```

`##` is visible to all sessions while session, that created temp global table is not terminated. Example:
Open two `SSMS` windows. In one create table `CREATE TABLE ##t (c INT NOT NULL );`
From other windows try selecting `SELECT * FROM ##t --no error`
Close first window. Try again `SELECT * FROM ##t --error. session that created temp global table was terminated`

So the answer is: if you need several sessions to use the same temp table you should use `##`, else use `#`. If there is just one batch then use `@`.

`@` variables are destroyed when the end of batch is reached.

`#` you can manually drop table or it will be destroyed when level it is created in terminates.

`##` you can manually drop table or it will be destroyed when session it is created in terminates.