# Creating temp tables in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a temptable in SQL SERVER and populate it with some data. For testing purposes, I highlighted the Create/insert/select statements in my SQL code, and it said 25 rows were affected. But when I do SELECT * from #tempCI, it says invalid object name #tempCI. Please look at the code below.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempCI
(
    UserID int,
    VendorName varchar(100),
    UnitCost decimal(18,4),
    UnitCount nchar(10),
    CostValue decimal(18,4)
)

INSERT INTO #TempCI
(
    UserID
    , VendorName
    , UnitCost
    , UnitCount
    , CostValue     
)

SELECT 
    1234
    , VendorName
    , InvValue
    , BegInvOnHand
    , BegCurrentValue
    From vVIEWWITHDATA;
```

When I highlight again the CREATE TABLE code, it tells me there an object with that name. When I try to DROP TABLE it says I cannot drop because it either doesn't exist or I don't have permission

Comment: The code you posted has a trailing comma after the CostValue column so this wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: error in copying the code. It says, 25 rows affected. It executes as it should.

Comment: Does this help? See the difference between # and ##. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219714/sql-server-tables-what-is-the-difference-between-and

Comment: That did it @Steve. Leave it as an answer and ill mark it complete

Comment: You won't be able to call a local temp table from outside the scope

Comment: Are you selecting from the temporary table in the same session? If not, try global temporary tables instead (tables starting with `##`).

Comment: Yes that worked. Steve (above) gave me that idea and I tried it and works.

Comment: Marked it as a duplicate so we can just close this one.