# What does # mean in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 
    ACCOUNT_NO,
    SUM(OPEN_BAL) AS OPEN_BAL,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), '') OPEN_BAL_EN,
INTO   
    #OB
```

Comment: # means temp table

Comment: Please at least do the google before asking any question

Comment: Kindly refer below link to get all details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219714/sql-server-tables-what-is-the-difference-between-and

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 1):

The `#` character denotes a [temporary table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#temporary-tables).

Comment: Why didn't you vote to close this obvious duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

## # character denotes Temp table, we add # as the prefix with temp table name

Ex:

```
    create table #TempTable
    (
        EmpID int, 
        EmpTitle Varchar(50),
        EmpName Varchar(50)
    )

    select * from #TempTable
```

Comment: Nice explanation with example.